# Magento Bundle Product - selecting variants of products

Tags: magento, bundle, set, product, variants

I have a trouble with adding a multiple selecting sets in bundle product.

I have a bundle product name Tunic Veto and It has a two variants of sets which customer can select - first, second or both

Set 1:
Tunic size. S - 3szt.
Tunic size. XL - 2szt.

Set 2:
Tunic size S - 10szt.
Tunic size. M - 5szt.

How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You should create separte Simple products which are linked to the bundled product you are referring to.

In the Magento backend you can select your Bundle product and then use Bundle Items menu to add the Simple products that can be selected by your customer. On this page you can create options and the belonging options with an input field of your choice (multiple select, dropdown, radio or checkbox). After creating an option it is possible to add the corresponding simple products.

Usually a dropdown menu will do, since it is likely that a customer will only choose one size. However in your question you are talking about a multiple select so you should choose which method will do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to create two or more possible product sets which customers can select, so we have:

Set 1:
Tunic size. S - 3szt. 
Tunic size. XL - 2szt.

Set 2:
Tunic size S - 10szt. 
Tunic size. M - 5szt.

I want to customers select SET 1, 2 or both NOT separate product form SETS

Comment: You can use grouped products to force the use of sets. However, grouped products are not available in bundled or configurable products yet, so this isn't an option either. One thing i can think of is to alter the javascript frontend in a way that only your predetermined sets are saleable. Or a bit nastier, use custom product options to choose a certain set. Stock tracking will not be possible in this last example.